# Define metric for systems of set of points

Tags: metrics, metric-spaces, computational-geometry

Given a set of points $p_1, p_2, ..., p_n$ and a collection of sets from $n$ points $S_1, S_2,...,S_m$. The pairwise distance between any three points $(p_1, p_2, p_3)$ satisfies triangle inequality $d(p_1,p_2) + d(p_2, p_3) \geq d(p_1, p_3)$. How to define the distance between sets such that the pairwise distance between any three sets $S_1, S_2, S_3$ satisfies triangle inequality $d(S_1,S_2) + d(S_2, S_3) \geq d(S_1, S_3)$. 
For example, when every set is $\textbf{pairwise disjoint}$ and has the $\textbf{same cardinality}$, we can define the distance between any two set to be the sum of the distances between elements of the two sets $$d(S_1, S_2) = \sum_{x \in S_1, y \in S_2} d(x,y)$$. we can show that the triangle inequality is satisfied for any three sets.

Answer (score 4):

[Hausdorff distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Distance_between_points_and_sets.3B_Hausdorff_distance_and_Gromov_metric) is what you are looking for.